# Own function should run every frame, how is this possible?

Tags: c#, function, collision, unity-game-engine

I created an own function within a script which should be executed as soon as there is a collision (using OnCollisionEnter).

The idea would be the following:

I have a ring which is steered by the key of the keyboard (Up and Down). Then I produced a sine wave wire with spheres which are moving from right to the left(in a sine wave manner). The player should not be able to move the ring trough the wire.

Therefore I add two colliders to the ring (an Up and a Down collider) and a collision script.

The problem is that sometimes the ring can me moved through the wire... when I press the Up key all the time. Even worse when I do nothing, then the ring should slides along the wire... but it does not.

I think the problem is related to the fact, that my own function is not executed every frame. Or what do you think? How can I execute my own function every frame?

Here the code of the collision script:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collUP)
{
    if (collUP.gameObject.name == "Sphere(Clone)") {

        Debug.Log ("Kollidiert mit UP"); 

        controller.MoveRingDown ();

    }

}
```

And here the code of the ring script in which I created an own function:

```
public void MoveRingDown() {

    transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3 (0f, -tilt, 0f);

}


public void MoveRingUp() {

    transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0f, tilt, 0f);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

OnCollisionEnter is only called once, when the collision produces ( as its names reads ). I think what you need is OnCollisionStay, which is executed while the collision lasts.